# How to cancel the current conversation in SDK4

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm currently trying to create a global interrupt so that if a user gets stuck in a conversation tree they can type "Cancel", this then should take the user out of whatever tree they are stuck in and allow them to start asking questions again. In SDK3 I had this working by using

```
bot.dialog('/cancel', (session) => {
        session.send('The current action has been cancelled. either try again or type "Help"');
        session.endDialog();
    })
    .triggerAction({
        matches: /cancel/i,
    });
```

Looking at the SDK4 documentation it recommends to use cancelAllDialogs to recreate similar functionality. however, whenever I'm trying to use it I keep getting 
"TypeError: turnContext.cancelAllDialogs is not a function".

the code I'm using to get this is

```
await turnContext.cancelAllDialogs(`The current action has been cancelled. either try again or type "Help"`);
```

am I using this incorrectly or missing a module somewhere, or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here should be `turnContext` as`cancelAllDialogs()` as [referred](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#to-clear-the-dialog-stack) to in the documentation exists within the [`dialogContext`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/dialogContext.ts#L128)

```
await dialogContext.cancelAllDialogs(`The current action has been cancelled. either try again or type "Help"`);
```

`turnContext` creates methods for the single back and forth currently occurring for your bot, whereas `dialogContext` is the wider scope of the conversation stack.